# Opening embedded MS Word application

Tags: javafx, ms-word, javafx-8

Is there any way to open MS Word within a JavaFX application? So the Word is running as an embedded program (within a Stage or Window).

I mean like a WebEngine, but it's a fully integrated MS Word.

Comment: Don't be too preoccupied with whether or not you can without stopping to think if you should. :P And no, I do not think that would be possible or remotely simple enough for a StackOverflow answer if it is.

Comment: Unfortunately this would be the solution for my problem. I'm afraid this can not be done because of JVM.

Comment: Eclipse seems to be able to open Word documents very well. So you could check its source code to find how they implement it. Although I assume it is not going to be an easy task to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I checked and tried.
I am able to open an embedded word in a Swing application, but not in JavaFX sadly. If you have any other tipp, please tell me

Comment: @Ansaldos, have you found any solution for JavaFX?

Comment: Hmm, not really. I solved with opening a Swing application which opens the embedded word (like Eclipce).